# How to manage acces control at login

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I been looking for control what a kind of user can see in my app, this is a scholar project. I'm using Swift and Firebase Authentication. I have two kinds of users: Model and Client. In my app I have some views for the Model and other for the Client. What I want to do is that once they log in, in to the app show just the views for their kind of user. I don't know how to verify if the user that is trying to sign in is a Model or a Client.

```swift
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if validateFields(){

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTxt.text!, password: passTxt.text!, completion:{
                (user, error) in
                if let u = user {
                    //User is found
                }else{
                    //Error
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I know that the code need to be where is the comment "User is found" but I don't know if I need to modify something into the the Firebase Console

Comment: How do you classify which users see Models and which users see Clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Firebase Database or Firestore to your project.
Now when you authenticate a user you should also create a userobject in your databse. In this object you can create a field to store whether your user is a model or a client.
Now once the user has signed in, you can download this userobject from the database, check whether the user is a model or client, and send the user to their corresponding views.

Comment: Thanks, this help me to much

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom claims.
You set them using the Admin SDK

```
// Javascript
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {model: true}).then(() => {
    // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
    // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

Then in client SDK just read the claim.

```
user.getIDTokenResult(completion: { (result, error) in
  guard let model = result?.claims?["model"] as? NSNumber else {
    // Something
  }
  if model.boolValue {
    // Show something else
  } else {
    // Something else again
  }
})
```

---

Shamelessly copied from [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)